# PHP date_format TIME not diplayed correctly using Joomla

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having some problems displaying the TIME Only (H:i) in a row.

```
    <td headers="qf_start_date" nowrap="nowrap"><?php echo date_format($course->start_date, '%H:%i'); ?></td>
```

This is the code, and as you can see, i want to see, under the start_date table in phpmyadmin, only Hours and minutes, nothing else. In the start_date query I want to have only, at the same time Y-m-d but i want to see in a page, only the hours and minutes...
I tried using date_format but it doesn't work...

What can i do?

I tried to include JDate but i think that i used a wrong sintax so i see blank page...

Thanks

To be more clear, visit: http://new.ivao.ch/index.php?option=com_seminarman&view=category&cid=4:rfe-geneva-departure&Itemid=227 and the table that i'm working in STD. It's blank...dunno why..
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can I ask what the raw value of `$course->start_date` is? For example, if it's straight from a DB `DATETIME` column, you may need to convert it to a UNIX timestamp first.

Comment: Yes, it's datetime type...How can I do that?

Comment: ``$course->start_date`` needs to be an object which implements [DateTimeInterface](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeinterface.php)

Answer (score 0):

please followw at below :

```
<?php
$date = "6.1.2009 13:00+01:00";
print_r(date_parse_from_format("j.n.Y H:iP", $date));
?>
```

or

```
<?php
$date = date_create('2000-01-01 12:15:25');
echo date_format($date, 'H:i:s');
?>
```

or

```
<?php
     $valid_date = date( 'm/d/y g:i A', strtotime($date));
?>
```

or

```
<td headers="qf_start_date" nowrap="nowrap">
<?php 
$valid_date = date( '%H:%i', strtotime($course->start_date));
echo $valid_date;
 ?>
```

Comment: Thank you Vikram for your reply. If i insert Y/m/d the date is showed correctly but the time is not displayed.

Comment: The question specifically requests `H:i` (hours:minutes) alone.

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like you're working with Joomla, you can use the `JDate` class to help you.

If your `$course->start_date` is a valid date string (can be converted with [`strtotime`](https://www.php.net/strtotime), you may do the following):

```
// May fix class JDate not found errors.  At the top of your script.
jimport( 'joomla.utilities.date' );

// ...

$date = new JDate($course->start_date)
echo $date->format('H:i');
```

Alternatively, (from the comments) it seems like your date string is not formatted as a UNIX timestamp. If you're not using Joomla, or do not want to use `JDate` you may use:

```
echo date('H:i', strtotime($course->start_date));
```

What's happening here is, for most date processing functions in PHP, you must pass it a valid UNIX timestamp.

A [UNIX timestamp](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php) is measurement of the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch on January 1st, 1970 at UTC.

You can convert most date strings into one (including mysql `DATETIME` columns by passing it into [php's `strtotime()` function](https://www.php.net/strtotime).

From there, you pass it into [`date`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) (or your desired date formatting function) with a [desired format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, i'm using joomla...Using strtotime() function, i still have the same problem...The time is 00:00...In phpmyadmin, the start_date is as: datetime formatted as: 0000-00-00 00:00:00
I want to have the year, month and day but this must be hidden in that page...Using the echo new jdate function i receive an error...Blank page...

Comment: Looking through the `JDate` docs, I can see that it's constructor doesn't return itself. I suggest, if using `JDate`, to split it into two lines. First: `$date = new JDate($course->start_date);` Then: `echo $date->format('H:i');` It also means you can use the same `$date` var for other formats elsewhere in the row.

Comment: How can i include the jdate here? Help me plz :)

Comment: Additionally, if you're using `JDate`, you may get an error saying the JDate class doesn't exist. If so, you may want to add `jimport( 'joomla.utilities.date' );` at the top of your script just to grab the class from Joomla Utilities.

Comment: Edited original answer with potential fixes.

Comment: The jimport is now included...So what should i change in the script that i made before?

Comment: If you've added the jimport line and used JDate like above, and still getting a blank page, you may want to check your error logs to find out what is causing the issue.

Comment: <td headers="qf_start_date" nowrap="nowrap"><?php echo date('H:i', strtotime($course->start_date)); ?></td> What should i change here?

Comment: <td ... ><?php $date = new JDate($course->start_date); echo $date->format('H:i'); ?></td>

Comment: First, thanks for your cooperation Sean, but, as you can see here: http://new.ivao.ch/index.php?option=com_seminarman&view=category&cid=4:rfe-geneva-departure&Itemid=227 the STD time is still as 00:00...On myadmin the start_date filed is as DATETIME formatted: 0000-00-00 00:00:00...If i see a flight anyway, in phpmyadmin i see 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000 Why that?